# How can I create time and date entries in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to create two time entries and two date entries in a mongo database.
I do not want to take a time and date stamp at the time the entry was created but I receive the time and date data on a post request and I store in the mongodb.
I also would like to know how would the date and time be defined in the schema.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. Did you read the mongo db documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just to give some background. I am writing an Android app where it needs to send a post request to a node.js server with start and end time and date.

On the app side, I just concatenated the time and date into one string in this format (day month year hours:mins:secs) and sent it in the post request.

On the server side in the post route:

```
router.post(...){
...
var start = new Date(req.body.startdate);
var end = new Date(req.body.enddate);
  var entry= new Entry(
        {
           ...
            startdate:start,
            enddate:end,
        });
Entry.create(entry, function(err, comment){
                ...  
                entry.save();
        });
}
```

The schema is just:

```
startdate:Date,
enddate:Date
```